# How to correctly detect the connected gamepad type?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to detect the type of controller connected to Unity. Here is what I have done:

```
var gamepad = Gamepad.current;
        var keyboard = Keyboard.current;
        if (gamepad == null && keyboard == null)
            return; // No gamepad connected.
        if (gamepad != null )
        {
            print(gamepad.displayName);
        }
```

and I have ps4 wired controller connected to my PC, but when I run the game This is what I get :
[image]

How is this even happening? Why doesn't print Xbox Controller when the PS4 controller is the one that is connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect the gamepad type like this:

```
    var gamepad = Gamepad.current;
    if (gamepad == null)
        return;
    if (gamepad is DualShockGamepad)
    {
        print("Playstation gamepad");
    }
    else if (gamepad is XInputController) 
    {
        print("Xbox gamepad");
    }
```

You can get these classes from:

```
using UnityEngine.InputSystem.DualShock;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem.XInput;
```

More info about supported gamepad types can be found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Gamepad.html).

Comment: Gamepad is not defined!

Answer (score 0):

I would guess whatever drivers / software you are using to make the PS4 controller work on Windows give it that display name. I don't think PS4 controller has official drivers / support for Windows.

Comment: I don't recall installing any driver. The ps4 controller is wired, so it works when I plug it in. I will try to install the right driver then, but I have a question, will this work for the other users that will install and play the game after publishing? I want to detect the correct controller type to guide the player through the game(tell them the name of buttons needed to perform specific actions in the game).

Comment: I dont know.. Just fyi gamepad support is basically broken in normal Unity. If you want gamepads to work well you need to use an asset like Rewired.